# Values from controller are not displayed

Tags: django, angularjs

I am trying to introduce Angular in my Django app. I doubt, that my problem is directly correlated with `interpolateProvider` which is needed because of django templates... but who knows.

I also have a problem with simplified version of that: http://jsfiddle.net/33417xsm/

This is my current version:

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/app/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-controller="MyAppController">
            [[ 2 + 4 ]]
            <p>[[ MyAppController.product.title ]]</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

file: app.js

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

    app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
                $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
                $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
        }
    );

    app.controller('MyAppController', function (){
        this.product = gem;
    });

    var gem = {
        'title': 'Inferno'
    };

})();
```

My result:
[image]

As you can guess, I want to also display `Inferno`. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app config is ok. But i see, you didn't understand clearly angular concept.

You must use $scope to binding data. Also you never need "myController.product" like this notation.

I updated your code http://jsfiddle.net/33417xsm/4/

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyAppController">
    {{ 2 + 4 }}
    <p>{{product.title}}</p>
</div>

var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyAppController', function ($scope){
    $scope.product = {"title":"product title"};
});
```

Comment: No this isn't wrong, but it isn't best practice. You can see clearly the difference, I updated here http://jsfiddle.net/33417xsm/6/

Comment: I have found a screencast about both approaches: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-an-alternative-approach-to-controllers